# Symfony custom form with validation

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, text, label

I created a simple form using official symfony documentation:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I would like to add a label or just whatever html text between the input text and the input date.

Can you help me ? Thanks

Update: twig code:

```
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

Comment: Please show how you render the form in Twig.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the different parts of your form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.task) }}
    <p>Here is my text.</p>
    {{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}
    {{ form_row(form.save) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

You should get the same result with a shorter form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.task) }}
    <p>Here is my text.</p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The `form_end(form)` function will display fields not rendered yet, here `dueDate` and `save`.

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) for more details.

Comment: Same answer same time, funny stuff.

Comment: Perfect synchronization! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to render the form manually:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'} } ) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{form_row(form.task)}}
    <div>Custom HTML Goes Here</div>
    {{form_row(form.dueDate)}}
    {{form_row(form.save)}}
{{form_end}}
```

Have a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html for more info

Or you can simplify this since form_end will render all unrendered fields do something like:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'} } ) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{form_row(form.task)}}
    <div>Custom HTML Goes Here</div>
{{form_end}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //You can add label in controller

 public function newAction()
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $objectQuestionnaire = new Questionnaire();
        $objectQuestionnaire->setName('Write name here');
        $objectQuestionnaire->setTextIntroduction("Put introduction here");

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($objectQuestionnaire)
            ->add('name', 'text',array('attr'=>array('label'=>'Name')))
            ->add('text_introduction', 'textarea',array('attr'=>array('label'=>'Text Introduction')))
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return $this->render('RecrutOnlineQuestionnaireBundle:Test:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }



   //If you do'nt want in controller then in view use separate fields 

   //like this 

   {{ form_row(form.name,{'attr':{'label':'Name'}}) }}
   {{ form_row(form.text_introduction,{'attr':{'label':'Text Introduction'}}) }}
   {{ form_row(form.save) }}
```